# Event or callback when webpack fails to load a module or chunk

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4

Is there some callback or Event in **webpack** to know when a module or chunk has failed to load in the browser?

I know that webpack can tell you that a certain module is not found when bundling, but suppose you make some changes to the scripts, but a user is already in the webapp... then the chunk names that were bundled earlier will not be found.

Below is such error that will appear:

```
fb81469e-872e-4459-b2ba-91ebfaf50d48.js:106 Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 28 failed.
```

Comment: https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack?at=5d762c273b1e5e5df17c91f7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i am being foolish, if you are loading dynamically with `import(...).then(...).catch(...)`, use the **catch** to handle the error, it could be chunk is not found, or simply a network failure. How am handling it is reloading the webapp.

If you are not not loading the module dynamically, then, use `try{...}catch(error) {...}` to handle the error, see https://gitter.im/webpack/webpack?at=5d762c273b1e5e5df17c91f7

Where was my head?

Comment: I'd be interested in whether there is a general / global event for this - I have an issue with this which I plan to eventually fix with a better deployment strategy but a global event could be a good stop gap measure

Comment: @Michael you can take control over the script tag injection yourself and attach a global event listener - https://dev.to/igor_bykov/handle-loading-errors-fallback-with-htmlwebpackplugin-2d31?signin=true